# Display validation error when TimeSpan model binding exceptions occur

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

In an ASP.NET MVC 4 application I have a view model that contains a nullable `TimeSpan` property:

```
[DisplayName("My time")]
public TimeSpan? MyTime { get; set; }
```

It is bound to an input element in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyTime)
```

The input box gets rendered with the help of a custom editor template `TimeSpan.cshtml`:

```
@model Nullable<System.TimeSpan>

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue
    ? Model.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm") : string.Empty),
    new { @class = "text-box single-line hasTimepicker" data_timepicker = true })
```

Now, if I enter the following two kinds of invalid times and submit the page I get the following different behaviour of the model binder:

- If I enter a letter, say `"a"` into the input element the `ModelError` for this property when I drill into the `ModelState.Values` collection has the `ErrorMessage` property set to a message (`"The value \"a\" for \"My time\" is invalid."`) and the `Exception` property is `null`. The bound value of `MyTime` is `null`.

  This `ErrorMessage` is displayed in the validation summary of the page.
- If I enter an invalid time, say `"25:12"`, into the input element the `ModelError` for this property has the `ErrorMessage` property set to an empty string but the `Exception` property set to an exception of type `InvalidOperationException` with an inner exception of type `OverflowException` telling me that `TimeSpan` could not be analysed because one of its numeric components is out of valid range. The bound value of `MyTime` is `null`.

  Again, the `ErrorMessage` is displayed in the validation summary of the page. But because it is empty it's not very useful.

Ideally for the second case of invalid input I would prefer to have the same kind of error message like for the first case, for example `"The value \"25:12\" for \"My time\" is invalid."`.

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit**

A custom validation attribute apparently doesn't help here because it is not called for the invalid input in the examples above when already the model binder detects invalid values. I had tried that approach without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the error is happening at model binding and that's where you need to be catching and checking it.

I have a Timespan model binder and editor template for `TimeSpan?` which should do what you need that's [up on Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaoaretasty/1671586)

Comment: The idea to create a model binder (which I wasn't very familiar with) and experimenting with your code pointed me into right direction although I did it differently in the end (see my own answer here). I learned something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Chao's answer brought me on the right track to use a custom model binder.

Because I wanted to keep as much functionality of the default model binder (flexibility of entered formats, localization, etc.) as possible unchanged and only have a useful error message for the user in the case when he enters `"25:12"` or similar I've created the following binder that just detects if the default model binder has added an `OverflowException` (as an inner exception) to the model state and if yes I add an error message to the state:

```
public class TimeSpanModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        object timeSpanValue = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        var modelState = bindingContext.ModelState[bindingContext.ModelName];
        var hasOverflowException = modelState.Errors
            .Any(e => e.Exception != null &&
                e.Exception.InnerException is OverflowException);

        if (hasOverflowException)
        {
            var rawValues = modelState.Value.RawValue as string[];
            if (rawValues != null && rawValues.Length >= 1)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName, string.Format(
                        "The value \"{0}\" for field \"{1}\" is invalid.",
                        rawValues[0],
                        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()));
            }
        }

        return timeSpanValue;
    }
}
```

Added in `global.asax`/`Application_Start()` to the `ModelBinders` collection:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeSpan), new TimeSpanModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeSpan?), new TimeSpanModelBinder());
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get this `ModelBinder` to bind with `AM/PM` format? It still complains when I submit a TimeSpan with format `11:45 PM`